# Error in cor.test.default(x = mat[, i], y = mat[, j], ...) : not enough finite observations

Tags: r, correlation, boxplot, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

I have looked on Google and on StackOverflow to find a solution to my problem. I have tried a few things now, and nothing seems to be working.

I am trying to create a correlation boxplot of linguistic features. For each feature (36 in total), there is a 1 in Excel for when a speaker used it, and a 0 for when a speaker did not.

There are 41 speakers, none of whom used all 36 features, though the lowest score is 8. I want to analyse my data to see which features correlate, and therefore find out which features predict the use of other features.

I have been using `corrplot` in R. Here is the command I have been using:

```
cor_mat <- df_analysis %>%
    replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
    cor(method = "spearman")

cor_residuals <- cor.mtest(cor_mat, conf.level = .95)
```

But, I get an error saying:

`Error in cor.test.default(x = mat[, i], y = mat[, j], ...) :    not enough finite observations`

Does anybody know why and how I can rectify it? In fact, all I really need to know is what the problem is, and I can probably figure it out on my own from there. Though I would be hugely grateful if you also have the solution!

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post your whole data set (via `dput()`, or somewhere we can download it easily ...)

Comment: Hi Ben. I put it into ```dput()```. The dataframe is called ```df_analysis```. Is there anything else you need from me?

Comment: I don't see the results edited into your question. The idea of `dput()` is that you paste the results as an edit into your question, so that we can access the full data set ...

Comment: I didn't save edits. There we go, should work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several columns in your data set that have no variation; thus the correlations for these variables are all `NA`, which screws things up downstream.

```
which(apply(df_analysis,2,sd)==0)
## [1] a' c[h]lach bheag [3] a' c[h]loich bhig [14] a' b[h]ord bheag 
##                     1                     3                    14 
##       [26] nan su[ ]l       [27] nan sul[ ] 
##                    26                    27
```

I figured this out by setting `options(error=recover)` and running to see where the error occurred (this setting drops you into browser/debug mode when an error occurs).  More directly, I *should* have done `corrplot(cor_mat)`, which helpfully puts question marks for NA values ...

[image]

`image()`, or `heatmap(as.matrix(df_analysis),Rowv=NA,Colv=NA, scale="none", margins=c(10,8))`, would be good for looking at your raw data.

Comment: This looks good, Ben. I am very happy you're helping me. But, could I ask how I get rid of those question marks? To support my argument in my thesis, I want to show the examiners that there is no variation of some features, and that some features correlate strongly with each others. e.g., ```[1] a' c[h]lach bheag``` and ```[16] ris an [t-]saor``` should show a strong correlation. 

Sorry if I'm asking you to do my work for me, but I'm getting a little desperate here! I've been struggling on my own because I'm worried about not doing my own work! If you have any suggestions, that'd be great!

Comment: You could ask a question about this on [CrossVaidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Any measure of correlation with a variable that has no observed variation will be impossible to measure ... or at least, I can't think of a sensible way to quantify that variation ...  The only way to get rid of the question marks is to drop those columns (which it sounds like you can't do ...)

Comment: Thank you, Ben! That's great. I think I know what I need to do! Really appreciate it!

Comment: If you think about, if everyone in your sample uses linguistic feature X, there won't be any information there to predict whether they are likely to use linguistic feature Y or not ...

Comment: Exactly! That just dawned on me and now it all makes sense. I can just put in my thesis that features that didn't vary were taken out of the analysis. And, in fact, I did that previously for the stats analysis in my MA I now remember. Gosh, so much time on something that was so obvious! I'll try to find the check-mark box. New to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can define corrplot ideally like this:

```
df_cor <- cor(df_analysis)
corrplot(df_cor, type = "full", order = "hclust",
         outline.color = "white", hc.method = "ward",
         pch.cex = .5, show.diag = TRUE,
         p.mat = cor_residuals$p, insig = "blank", sig.level = .01,
         addrect = 20, tl.srt = 36, tl.cex = .8, tl.col = "black",
         col = rev(lacroix_palette("PassionFruit", 8, "continuous")))
```

Comment: Hi Jovan,


So, my raw data is in an Excel spreadsheet.

I got R to read the spreadsheet, then I created a dataframe to analyse. It worked very well on a different Excel spreadsheet, but it's not working on this one.

So, in the ```df_analysis``` I have a dataframe with 36 features (42 rows, including a heading row, then 41 speakers' responses).

I'd be happy to show you more, but I am not sure how to do that.

I am a sort of 'trial and error' R user, rather than a competent R user!

Comment: I think you can show me how your data looks like? corrplot here needs the input of your dataframe correlation matrix, so basically I was seeing that you somehow missed to include it above..

Comment: and I realized that you use dplyr pipe, and it doesn't necessary I think, you can directly call the cor_mat to corrplot

Comment: no I mean the content of your dataframe, you can use head(df_analysis) or str(df_analysis), and then update it in the question, so I know what kind of data you wanted to make a corrplot

Comment: This is an example of the dataframe:

```[1] a' c[h]lach bheag [2] a' chlach b[h]eag [3] a' c[h]loich bhig [4] a' chlo[i]ch bhig
Nessf                             1                     1                     1                     1
```

Comment: please run head(df_analysis) or str(df_analysis), and update to question, that will be helpful

Comment: The command I put in to create the dataframe was this:

```
df_analysis <- sgds_data %>%
    filter(!is.na(township)) %>%
    column_to_rownames("township") %>%
    select(-matches("lat"), -matches("lon"), -id, -district, -census_point, -sgds_point, -aggregate,
           -matches("1891"), -matches("gender"), -matches("yob"), -matches("label"))
```

Comment: no i was just asking what is your df_analysis contains? does running head(df_analysis) or str(df_analysis) didn't produce anything?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added it to the question above. I just gave a sample because I was warned to be careful about sharing data. Anyway, it's a good sample because it shows what the data looks like. Every column has a 1 or a 0. No empty cells.

Comment: I see, so you have a logistic dataset